# Subversion Repository Autocomplete

Tags: svn, autocomplete

When entering something like

```
svn checkout file:///var/svn/repos/my-projects
```

I can use  to autocomplete up to repos/ but after that I can't. I know that Subversion's files in the repository don't mirror a standard directory structure so that is probably the reason.

However, if I'm checking out just one file its a pain to try to remember the whole path or even type it out.

Is there anyway to autocomplete the whole way? Or is it standard practice to just checkout the whole repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using bash there is almost certainly a [bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) script you could use. A quick search reveals an extremely promising script hosted in the offical Subversion repository: [../tools/client-side/bash_completion](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/bash_completion).

I may well use this myself!

Answer (score -2):

Try [tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).  It helps you do all this from the explorer (Assuming you're on windows).

Comment: The path `file:///var/svn/repos/my-projects` implies that he is not using Windows, although it is still possible he is.

Comment: It is possible he is using something like `cygwin`, though you are right, it is unlikely.